# mysqli_connect() not working with bluemix

Tags: php, mysqli, deployment, ibm-cloud, buildpack

I deployed php application to bluemix but mysqli_connect function not working...
        then i searched and find about php buildpack
        i add buildpack to mainfiest.yml file

```
applications:
    - path: .
      memory: 128M
      instances: 1
      domain: mybluemix.net
      name: Registeration
      host: registeration
      disk_quota: 1024M
      buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git
```

its not working still..... so i find another solution that create .bp-config/option.json file in project directory... and write under the file

```
    {
        "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["mysqli"]
    }
```

still mysqli_function is not working..... But When i open my project in wampserver it sucessfuly connect with bluemix server so there is no problem with code....but problem is when i open project on bluemix then mysqli_connect function not working...

please help me.....

Answer (score 2):

Set your composer.json to

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-mysqli": "*"
  }
}
```

Use this Bluemix PHP MySQL sample as an example: https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/php-mysql